# Jhipster cloudfoundry command giving "incorrect usage" error

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, jhipster

I am trying to deploy my first Jhipster app to cloud foundry.

My yo jhipster:cloudfoundry command is showing an error "incorrect usage". Presumably while binding to the mysql database service?

The "services" tab in cloud foundry is showing only one SERVICE INSTANCE of p-mysql with SERVICE PLAN of ClearDB MySQL Database Spark DB.

```
C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006>yo jhipster:cloudfoundry
CloudFoundry configuration is starting
? Name to deploy as: modeldr006
? Which profile would you like to use? dev
? What is the name of your database service? p-mysql
? What is the name of your database plan? ClearDB MySQL Database Spark DB

Creating Cloud Foundry deployment files
identical deploy\cloudfoundry\manifest.yml

Checking for an existing Cloud Foundry hosting environment...

Creating your Cloud Foundry hosting environment, this may take a couple minutes...
Creating the database
FAILED
Incorrect Usage.


NAME:
   create-service - Create a service instance

ALIAS:
   cs

USAGE:
   cf create-service SERVICE PLAN SERVICE_INSTANCE

EXAMPLE:
   cf create-service cleardb spark clear-db-mine

TIP:
   Use 'cf create-user-provided-service' to make user-provided services available to cf apps
```

One thing I dont understand is how Jhipster is asking for 2 variables of p-mysql and ClearDB MySQL Database Spark DB. But the usage is showing 3, being SERVICE PLAN SERVICE_INSTANCE. The plan I am on is spark but it is not asking for that.

The push to cloud foundry at the end of the script also fails, maybe because of the prior error.

```
Uploading modeldr006...

FAILED
Error uploading application.
GetFileAttributesEx C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\*.war: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

× { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ClearDB, then you must answer:

- What is the name of your database service? cleardb
- What is the name of your database plan? spark

The service and plan are given to you when you do a "cf marketplace".

We do not pre-configure those in JHipster, as it depends on your CloudFoundry provider (here you use Pivotal, but there are others), and as we do not want to advertise companies providing paying services.

Comment: ooh, it is creating a new service instance, not binding to an existing one! Many thanks.